# How to silently login with Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I am trying to login through Windows Authentication from my browser. The problem is, I always need to go through a login pop up, type in my Windows' user credentials before I can get through. What do I need to do to silently get through?

Comment: What do you mean by "silent"? Are you perhaps referring to SSO (single sign-on)?

Comment: This is a browser configuration. Browsers will usually _not_ pass your Windows credentials automatically to untrusted sites. You will need to configure the sites to allow your browser to do that. How to do that depends on the browser.